# How to load Multiple Images synchronously in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

The following code is loading the images correctly but the problem is that its loading all the images asyncronously. How to display all the images one by one syncronously?

```
@ViewChild('canvas') public canvas: ElementRef;
ImagesWidth: number = 32;
ImagesHeight: number = 32;
images: string = "../assets/blackBoards/Balllmage_";
imageExtension: string = ".png"
@Input() public width = 600;
@Input() public height = 500;

private cx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

public ngAfterViewInit()
{
    const canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
    this.cx = canvasEl.getContext('2d')!;
    let image = new Image();

    canvasEl.width = this.width;
    canvasEl.height = this.height;

    image.onload = () => {
    this.cx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
}

image.src = require("../assets/blackBoards/NCAA_mhalfcourt_500x410.png");
let j = 0;
for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

    let myimages = new Image();
    let v = j * this.ImagesHeight;

    myimages.onload = () => {
        this.cx.drawImage(myimages, 0, v, this.ImagesWidth, this.ImagesHeight);

    }
    myimages.src = require("../assets/blackBoards/BallImage_" + j + ".png");
}
```

Comment: The browser makes network requests async. Trying to get them sync defeats everything the browser does to provide a good user experience. Why do you want them sync?

Comment: I want to add a image as background and then display all the images on it.

Comment: How is that related to sync/async?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `Promise` for each image and use `Promise.all()` to wait them all to finish:

```
function loadImage(image, src) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    image.onload = () => resolve();
  }
  image.src = require(src);
}
```

and then

```
let imagesUrls = ['asd', 'asd2'];
let images = [new Image(), new Image()];
Promise.all(images.map((e, i) => loadImage(e, imagesUrls[i]))).then(() => {
  // your code here
});
```

get it as a concept, maybe integrating error handling `image.onerror = () => ...`